# Como capturar status do windows (suspenso/hibernando) via código Delphi

Tags: delphi

Gostaria de verificar o status do windows (suspenso/hibernando) antes de executar uma ação.

**Exemplo**

```
if suspenso=true then
   //executa algo
```

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Caro @RobertodeCampos o que o AP quer é saber o estado do windows e não do app, no caso suspenso ou hibernando.

Comment: Não tinha visto o titulo, vou remover o comentário

Comment: Não sei como funciona com Delphi, mas provavelmente vai ter que ser algum tipo de "bind" com kernel32 ou PowrProf, no caso esta função: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-getdevicepowerstate - mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Olhando melhor a doc da microsoft a função que provavelmente vai atende-lo é [`PowerSettingRegisterNotification`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Powersetting/nf-powersetting-powersettingregisternotification) (lib Powrprof), ela executa um callback quando as configurações de energia são modificadas (creio que vá ter que combinar com getdevicepowerstate), ou então a função que parece ser propria para isto [`RegisterSuspendResumeNotification`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-registersuspendresumenotification)

Answer (score 2):

Com base no comentário do @Guilherme-nascimento e [este artigo da microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/Power/wm-powerbroadcast) consegui montar um exemplo utilizando a mensagem WM_POWERBROADCAST , que é disparada no momento que o windows entra e suspensão. O retorno da mensagem na propriedade PowerEvt é o atual status, aonde PBT_APMSUSPEND representa que esta entrando em suspensão e PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC representa que esta saindo da suspensão:

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    fSuspenso: Boolean;
    procedure AlterouStatusDoWindows(var Msg: TWMPower); message WM_POWERBROADCAST;
  public
  end;

...
procedure TForm1.AlterouStatusDoWindows(var Msg: TWMPower);
begin
  case MSg.PowerEvt of
    PBT_APMSUSPEND: fSuspenso := True;
    PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC: fSuspenso := False;
  end;
end;
```